# Need help with an inequality proof

Tags: inequality

Show that if $a$ and $h$ are positive numbers, $h < a^2$, then

$$\sqrt{a^2 + h} - a < \frac h{2a} < a - \sqrt{a^2 - h} $$

I spent quite a while working on it, but I got nowhere.

Comment: Rearrange. You want to prove $$\sqrt{a^2+h} < a + \frac{h}{2a}$$ and $$\sqrt{a^2-h} < a - \frac{h}{2a}.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Wow, thanks. Seems really obvious in retrospect. How do I signify that this question is now resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First
$$ \sqrt{a^2+h}-a=\frac{h}{\sqrt{a^2+h}+a}<\frac{h}{2a} $$
and do the same thing for $a-\sqrt{a^2-h}$.